# Different layouts for single activity

Tags: android, android-activity, xml-layout

I want to create different view states for error and success of login page. For that I want to create the singe activity (login), Which will have email and password fields. After submitting the data if I'm getting success/error then I want to display different layout (not in different activity). How can I achieve that ? Simpy.. I need to display multiple layouts on single activity on changing its states.

Comment: Use [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Comment: you should use Fragments

Comment: Yes using fragment is also an option. But I want to implement it using "merge" if possible. Do you have any idea of implementing that using merging layouts?

Answer (score 0):

ok here simple one , say you want three layouts : creates 3 linearLayouts or Relative layouts for every states by default set their visibility to gone and give them ids find them by id (findViewByID) and than in every state use `linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
and the others

```
linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE); linearLayout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and so on with every new state

Comment: No I don't want to do that using visibility. Thanks for replying. I want to implement it using "merge" if possible.

Comment: you can still add view programmatically in the activity if you dont want that